# Can Conga Use One Template Multiple Times in one solution?

Tags: pdf, master-detail, conga

We have to produce an official document from information contained in two custom objects that have a master-detail relationship. I can have one template for the master object and another template for the detail object. What we'd like to do is have one solution that stitches together the merged info for the master record and merged info FOR EACH detail record, effectively using the same detail object template over and over for every detail record. Is this possible to do with conga?... or maybe in conjunction with Visualforce or apex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a template ID in the Conga URL.
The best practice by Conga is to store that ID in a technical field, hidden from page layouts.

Master Object :

```
https://composer.congamerge.com?SessionId={!API.Session_ID}&ServerUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_210}&Id={!Master__c.Id}&OFN={!Master__c.Name}&templateId={!Master__c.TECH_Template_ID__c}
```

Detail Object :

```
https://composer.congamerge.com?SessionId={!API.Session_ID}&ServerUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_210}&Id={!Detail__c.Id}&OFN={!Detail__c.Master__r.Name}&templateId={!Detail__c.TECH_Template_ID__c}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (and need to) do this with a single template.

While you can specify multiple template IDs, it will simply output all of them, they will not be stitched together.

See https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Advanced_Composer_Solutions/Composer_Tips_and_Tricks/Streamlining_Template_Selection_in_Conga_Composer

> With multiple templates specified and the output format set to Adobe PDF, the system will convert each output files to PDF, join the collection and return a single PDF.
>
> With multiple templates specified and the output format set to Same as Template, the system will return a zipped file containing each output file.

Instead, in a single template, you can include the results from multiple reports or queries (up to 50 I believe).

When you are doing a point merge from a single record, say the master, you can filter all reports on the master id, and can include the info from the child records in your single template.